# How do I trigger Xdebug from within a Vagrant's SSH via CURL?

Tags: curl, ssh, vagrant, xdebug, homestead

So I have a Vagrant-driven instance, running two projects, and all works swimmingly. My project has a server instance, and a client instance. They communicate over REST ... and all is well there too.

So, I have Xdebug set up correctly - I know this, because if I call my Laravel Client instance using CLI cURL from *outside* Homestead, passing ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=vagrant, it picks it up in PhpStorm and I can debug as normal:

```
curl -v http://clientproject.dev?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=vagrant
```

Now, if I make the ***exact same call***, from within Homestead's CLI (i.e. I've SSH'd into the Vagrant box, and run the curl command as shown above), it doesn't trigger. This makes no sense to me

I've scoured the net without much joy, and I'm hoping you fine citizens have come across this?

I'm really wanting this so that I can have my server instance call my client instance with XDEBUG cookies so that in development, it makes debugging easier for my developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after digging around and understanding a bit more about how Xdebug works, I realised that it wasn't working, because for Xdebug to work, the originating call must take place on the same machine as your IDE.

Because I was making a CURL call inside the Homestead VM, XDebug was making it all the way back to the IDE.

To correct this, you have to set a header in your curl call, like so:

```
curl -v http://myclient.dev?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=vagrant --header "X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.10.01"
```

Where of course, **192.168.10.01** is the IP of the Vagrant's host machine, i.e. where my IDE resides.

All working now!